# difference between layout and layout-400dp-land

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-screen

The requirement for the app is that it  should work on all devices. To support this I have

following layout defs-

```
layout/
layout-land/
layout-sw400dp-port/
layout-sw400dp-land/
layout-sw600dp-port/
layout-sw600dp-land/
layout-sw7200dp-port/
layout-sw7200dp-land/
```

its working fine for 7" and 10" tablets.

for the `sw400dp` devices ie 5" devices like Samsung Note etc, they are using `layout/` and
`layout-land/`. How can I force these devices to use 
`layout-sw400dp-port/` and `layout-sw400dp-land/`

Comment: what is the os version of the device you are using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't**

The original Note runs GingerBread (2.3) and the `sw-` identifiers only work from 3.2 upwards.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

> The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.
>
> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier

Devices < 3.2 will not use the `-sw` layouts. To support all API levels you will need to provide layouts using both types of qualifiers.

Check out this post:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

> Previous versions of the platform will ignore any resources using the new resource qualifiers. This, then, is one approach that will work:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For phones
res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml    # For pre-3.2 tablets
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 3.2 and up tablets
```

Comment: A phone of 480x854 pix and physical size of 5" with android 4.1.1 takes layout/ not from layout-sw400dp/. My requirement is a different layout for bigger phones but all phones are taking res/layoyt, even phones with android 3.2 and up ignoring layout-sw400dp/.

Comment: The measurement is in dp, not px, so it depends on the density of your device. 480px is not greater than 400dp at xhdpi.

Comment: @RKN you're right! That's what I meant :) Anyway, so it won't pick up `sw400dp` in this case

Comment: Thanks!!  now I understand. I was confusing dp with physical dimension of device. I was doing 2.5 (physical width of device) * 160. Just to make my understanding clear - Galaxy S4 1080x1920 (5") = 540dp, S -III 720x1280 (4.8") = 350 dp. Am I correct ?

Comment: @RKN - Are you based in NCR ?